# How to include Poppler for docker build

Tags: python, docker

I use [this](https://github.com/mathewskevin/pdf-to-cbz/blob/master/pdf_to_cbz.py) script to convert pdf into cbz. For Windows no problem, just add Poppler bin folder into PATH
But I try to understand how can I include to install [Poppler](https://github.com/cbrunet/python-poppler) into my Dockerfile (for bot development)

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y unrar

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Is it just necessary to add `pip install python-poppler` in `requirements.txt` or do I need to install something else as a separate package?

Comment: Have you read the [Poppler requirements listing](https://cbrunet.net/python-poppler/installation.html#requirements)?  Does the Dockerfile you show work; if not, what goes wrong?  Normally I might expect to run the `pip install` command in your non-Docker development virtual environment, then use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to regenerate the requirements file.

Comment: @DavidMaze 

I solved the compilation problem, several additional packages were missing, I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240998/how-to-install-poppler-0-73-on-ubuntu-20-04-any-change-since-18-04) guide and then set the environment variables

Comment: why not just use `apt-get install poppler-utils` ?

Comment: @jkr You're right, the problem is that with some Linux distributions I had problems, it gave me problems telling me that the compiler was missing etc (I tested on Vultr on Ubuntu 22)

Comment: gotcha. you would also have to install gcc and g++, because the poppler python package includes C++ code, so you'd need the compiler too

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way to set-up Poppler for a docker

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    tar \
    cmake \
    libnss3 \
    libnss3-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libgif-dev \
    cmake \
    libblkid-dev \
    e2fslibs-dev \
    libboost-all-dev \
    libaudit-dev \
    libopenjp2-7-dev \
    g++  # Aggiunto il pacchetto g++

RUN wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-21.09.0.tar.xz \
    && tar -xvf poppler-21.09.0.tar.xz \
    && cd poppler-21.09.0 \
    && mkdir build \
    && cd build \
    && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
             -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
             -DTESTDATADIR=$PWD/testfiles \
             -DENABLE_UNSTABLE_API_ABI_HEADERS=ON \
             .. \
    && make \
    && make install

WORKDIR /app
COPY poppler.py /app/poppler.py

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENV PATH="/poppler-21.09.0/build/utils:${PATH}"

CMD ["python", "poppler.py"]
```